Adding an outlet from an existing switch outlet
I have an existing outlet that is switch controlled.  I want to add another outlet from the existing outlet that will be half switch controlled and half always on.  Can I do this with the wiring shown in the picture?  If so which wires I need to connect to the new outlet?

All the neutral wires connect together. That's all of the white wires except for the white wire that is combined with two blacks in the red wire nut that is hanging out of the box.
Switched hot is the black currently on the receptacle.
Always hot is one of the blacks in that red wire nut.
For the new receptacle you will need all three of those wires plus ground. If the circuit is a 15A circuit (check the breaker) then you can use 14 AWG wire (14/3 cable) or 12 AWG wire (12/3 cable). If it is a 20A circuit then you must use 12 AWG wire (12/3 cable).
Since everything here is cables, we'll stick with cables. Standard cables are black/red/white plus bare ground.
In the existing box:

Bare (ground) connects to the other grounds - hard to see but I think that's the wire nut in the bottom of the box.
White (neutral) connects to the other neutrals. There are a bunch of ways of doing that, but the simplest is to connect to one of the screws next to one of the white wires on the receptacle. Note that the existing wires on the receptacle (except ground) are in "backstab" connections which are notoriously unreliable. So you may want to connect the two existing white wires from the receptacle, the new white wire and a short white wire ("pigtail") together with a wire nut and connect the other end of the pigtail to one of the receptacle screws.
By convention, red is switched hot. Connect it to one of the screws on the hot (black wire) side of the receptacle. Consider moving the backstabbed black wire to the other screw for a more reliable connection.
Connect black (always hot) to the two black/one white wire nut. You may need a new wire nut, but a red wire nut should be OK with 4 14 AWG or 12 AWG wires.

In the new box:

White to a neutral side screw
Black to one hot side screw
Red to the other hot side screw
Bare ground to the ground screw
Remove the tab that connects the two hot side screws


Is it possible to make the existing outlet always on or half hot and half  switch with the new outlet being half hot and half switch?

Yes, any of these are possible.

What would I need to change in the instructions you gave to make the existing outlet always on and the new outlet half on  and  half switch controlled.  Thanks so much for your help!!

Mark the black wire going to the receptacle with red tape to indicate "switched-hot". That's for convenience/easy understanding, and is not a code requirement.
Mark the white wire in the black bundle with black tape, that is "always-hot" and that marking is a code requirement.
Pigtail the neutrals going to the outlet with a white pigtail.  (neutral)
Now, simply come off that receptacle with /3+ground cable, pigtailing each wire into the same-color wires existing in the box (now that we have re-marked them colors.  You'd need to pigtail the reds or use the receptacle as a splice.
At the other receptacle, split the hot side and send red and black to different sockets. Don't split the neutral side.
Feel free to split this receptacle too, if you want.

One of the 2 black wires tied together with a white wire (In the red wire nut) is constant hot.  It is there that you can tie in a hot to another outlet that will be constant hot. ( The white goes to the switch and returns as the black on the outlet. Completing the switched outlet, on a switch loop that is no longer allowed by code.)
The new neutral gets tied together with the others and pigtailed to the switched outlet
All grounds are tied together.

Switch loops controlling receptacles are still permitted to omit neutral

@ThreePhaseEel,  Really!   I thought every switch or outlet box had to have a neutral?   I'll update my brain. Thanks.
